# Symfony2 - Apenas um campo têm o seu valor lido, os demais deste mesmo campo ficam NULL ao submeter formulário

Tags: mysql, checkbox, symfony-2, doctrine-2, null

Tenho duas tabelas relacionadas: **material** e **items_budget**. A tabela **items_budget** tem um formulário que tem um campo que lista o nome de todos os **material** em um grupo de `checkbox`, e ao lado de cada `checkbox` tem dois campos `input`, um para *quantity* e outro para *price*. Abaixo está o código para a listagem desses Material

```
<strong>Materiais</strong>
{% for material in materials %}
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="itemsbudget_material" name="cdg_itemsbudget_type[material]" value="{{ material.id }}"> {{ material.name }} - 
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" class="itemsbudget_price_hidden" value="{{ material.price }}"/>
        <input type="text" class="itemsbudget_quantity" name="cdg_itemsbudget_type[quantity]" placeholder="Qtd" size="3"/>x - R$
        <input type="text" class="itemsbudget_price" name="cdg_itemsbudget_type[price]" value="0" size="3" readonly/>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Eu também tenho uma trigger que é executada toda vez que novos dados são persistidos na tabela **items_budget**. Ela subtrai a *quantity* inserida da *currentQuantity* do **material**. Funciona perfeitamente, porém agora vem o problema: apenas funciona **para o primeiro registro da tabela material**, porque para os outros a *quantity* misteriosamente fica NULL após submeter o formulário

Eu tentei adicionar no fim de cada atributo `name` um par de colchetes, mas ao fazer isso, o formulário simplesmente é recarregado e nenhum dado é persistido.

Eu realmente quero deixar isto o mais claro possível, então eu montei uma imagem dos passos que eu segui. Do canto superior esquerdo ao inferior direito: primeiramente marquei a opção que corresponde ao **primeiro** registro da tabela **material**, entrei com um valor aleatório para *quantity* e então submeti o formulário. Conforme a segunda imagem, tudo funcionou normalmente. Mas agora, as outras duas imagens demonstram o problema. Marquei outra opção qualquer e entrei novamente com um valor para a *quantity*, mas desta vez o campo fica NULL, como pode ser visto na última imagem.

[image]

Aqui, apenas a classe `ItemsBudgetController` e seu método `addAction`:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ItemsBudgetType());
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $ItemsBudgetEntity = $form->getData();
            $manager->persist($ItemsBudgetEntity);
            $manager->flush();

            $BudgetEntity = $form->get('budget')->getData();
            $BudgetEntity->addItemsBudget($ItemsBudgetEntity);

            $manager->persist($BudgetEntity);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Materiais para o orçamento adicionados');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_budgets'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('PanelBundle:ItemsBudget:index.html.twig', array(
        'budgets' => $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Budget')->findAll(),
        'materials' => $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Material')->findAll()
    ));
}
```

E agora, o `ItemsBudgetType`, onde configuro o campo `material` como uma entidade:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('budget', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PanelBundle:Budget',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                ),
            ))
            ->add('material', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PanelBundle:Material',
                'attr' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                ),
            ))
            ->add('quantity', 'number', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                ),
            ))
            ->add('price', 'money', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                ),
            ));
}
```

Isto não faz sentido. Por que apenas o primeiro registro tem o seu campo *quantity* "visto"? Se você precisar que eu poste mais códigos, atualizarei a pergunta.

**Edição #1**

Vou mostrar a relação entre as tabelas. Ao conferir como fazer um campo como collection com uma entidade, entendi que só funciona com relações manyToMany.

Primeiro, `Material`:

```
CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Material:
    type: entity
    table: material
    repositoryClass: CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\MaterialRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        description:
            type: string
            length: 255
        currentQuantity:
            type: integer
            column: current_quantity
        price:
            type: decimal
        dateCreated:
            type: datetime
    oneToMany:
        itemsBudget:
            targetEntity: ItemsBudget
            mappedBy: material
        quantityMaterial:
            targetEntity: QuantityMaterial
            mappedBy: material
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Então, `ItemsBudget`:

```
CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\ItemsBudget:
    type: entity
    table: items_budget
    repositoryClass: CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\ItemsBudgetRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        quantity:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
        price:
            type: decimal
    manyToOne:
        budget:
            targetEntity: Budget
            inversedBy: itemsBudget
            joinColumn:
                name: budget
                referencedColumnName: id
        material:
            targetEntity: Material
            inversedBy: itemsBudget
            joinColumn:
                name: material
                referencedColumnName: id
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: EU não entendi bem a sua questão, talvez você deva dar uma limpeza e ser mais claro. Mas, ainda assim, me parece que isso soa como se você precisasse usar collection Field Type: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: @felipsmartins Oi! Aquele primeiro código à mostra é o que cria os `checkbox`, conforme a imagem. A situação é que os `input` para digitar uma quantidade, ao submeter o formulário, eles ficam NULL, exceto para o primeiro registro da tabela **material**, apenas este problema, entende?

Comment: @felipsmartins Eu tenho uma tabela **items_budget** específica para guardar o idenficador do orçamento e do material, e se houver mais de um, iterar sobre esse conjunto de resultados e persistir na tabela. Será que esta coleção seria mesmo ideal?

Comment: Não tenho certeza se Collection Type Field é a opção, estou apenas a desconfiar pelo meu entendimento geral do que você abordou (pelo fato também de apenas o primeiro campo ser gravado) e também pelo que já passei antes. Houve um sistema onde havia entidades OCORRÊNCIAS e ANEXOS. Uma OCORRÊNCIA pode ter vários ANEXOS então eu precisei usar Collection Type Field no meu form OCORRÊNCIA. EStou sem tempo pra avaliar melhor o caso, mas caso queira me adicionar no skype, meu ID é: fmartinsdev

Comment: @felipsmartins Entendi. Na verdade, vendo a imagem, todos os MATERIAL que eu selecionar serão gravados, porém apenas o _quantity_ fica NULL. Nota-se que nem mesmo o _price_ fica, pois ele aparece com "0". Há algum problema apenas com aquele campo.

Comment: @felipsmartins Estava vendo criação de collections com entidades, e parece que para funcionar as tabelas devem ter uma relação manyToMany, correto? Será que a relação com as tabelas mencionadas na pergunta esteja errada? Eu vou atualizar com estas informações